# Search query - exact post title match

Tags: posts, wp-query, query, search, wp-title

I have a bunch of posts titled something like this...

- English Language 2015
- English Language 2016
- English Language 2017
- English Language 2018

And on each one of these posts I have a dropdown select menu displaying posts with the same title, but different year. Here is my code for this. I am using Relavanssi plugin by the way:

```
<?php global $post;

$the_title = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', ' ', $post->post_title);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    's'         => $the_title,
    'sentence'  => true,            
    'exact'     => true,    
    'orderby'   => 'title',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'showposts' => -1
);  

$query = new WP_query($args);

relevanssi_do_query($query); 

    if ($query->post_count > 1) { ?>

        <h4>Years</h4>

        <select onchange="location = this.value;">

            <option disabled selected value>Select Year</option>

            <?php

            foreach ($query->posts as $r_post) {

                if ($r_post->ID == $post->ID ) continue;
                $link = get_permalink($r_post->ID);
                $title = get_the_title($r_post->ID);

                echo "<option value='$link'>$title</option>";

            }

            ?>

        </select>

 <?php } ?>
```

As you can see, I'm looking for the current post title and removing the years.

All good, HOWEVER, if I have more posts called something like...

- English Language and Literature 2015
- English Language and Literature 2016
- English Language and Literature 2017
- English Language and Literature 2018

...these posts will also display in the dropdown menu in the above 'English Language' posts, as it's picking up the phrase 'English Language', but I want an **exact** search query so it only displays 'English Language' posts on the dropdown of these posts.

I tried wrapping the $the_title var in quotes in attempt to do a phrase search but this did nothing.